# Getting age automatically when given Date of Birth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wanted to get the age of a person from his date of birth. I have a HTML code where I'm using a datepicker for dob, when I give the date-of-birth it show automatically show the age without giving submit. Please help me in finding a solution for this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            DOB calculations
        </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='jquery-ui.css' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'>
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui.min.js'>
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'>
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui-custom.js'>
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.ui.datepicker.js'>
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    //firstDay: 1,
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                        dateText.split('/');
                        Bdate = new Date(dateText[2], dateText[0] - 1, dateText[1]);
                        BDateArr = ('' + Bdate).split(' ');
                        //document.getElementById('DOW').value = BDateArr[0]; 
                        Cdate = new Date;
                        CDateArr = ('' + Cdate).split(" ");
                        Age = CDateArr[3] - BDateArr[3];
                        document.getElementById('AGE').value = Age;
                        // DOBcalc(dateText); 
                        //DOBcalc(); 
                    }
                })

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            DOB (mm/dd/yyyy):
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" value=''>
            Age:
            <input id="AGE" type="text" value="">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try using this function as your `onSelect` event handler instead:

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var today = new Date(),
            dob = new Date(value),
            age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

        $('#age').text(age);
    },
    maxDate: '+0d',
    yearRange: '1920:2010',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

This should be very accurate (and much better than my old code), since everything's been handed off to the native `Date` object.

See a simple demonstration of this here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/PHvYK/1

Comment: will return NaN for 17/06/1986 if the format of the date is "dd/mm/yy"

Answer (score 2):

```
function getAge(birth) {
   var today = new Date();
   var curr_date = today.getDate();
   var curr_month = today.getMonth() + 1;
   var curr_year = today.getFullYear();

   var pieces = birth.split('/');
   var birth_date = pieces[0];
   var birth_month = pieces[1];
   var birth_year = pieces[2];

   if (curr_month == birth_month && curr_date >= birth_date) return parseInt(curr_year-birth_year);
   if (curr_month == birth_month && curr_date < birth_date) return parseInt(curr_year-birth_year-1);
   if (curr_month > birth_month) return parseInt(curr_year-birth_year);
   if (curr_month < birth_month) return parseInt(curr_year-birth_year-1);
}

var age = getAge('18/01/2011');
alert(age);
```

Comment: This is nice function if you have the date in a different format from default

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract two `Date` objects in javascript, you get their difference in milliseconds so `( BDate - (new Date()) )/365.25/24/60/60/1000` will give you an age result that should be accurate to within a day. (i.e. if their birthday is today and its a leap year it may be inaccurate)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#dtp').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                //firstDay: 1,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var d = new Date(Date.parse(inst.lastVal));
                    var diff = (new Date()).getFullYear() - d.getFullYear();
                    document.getElementById('AGE').value = diff;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: you need to give var d = new Date((inst.input.val())); instead of var d = new Date(Date.parse(inst.lastVal));
 to work properly

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code very simple

```
function agefinding()
    {
        var birthDay = document.getElementById("TxtDOB").value;
        var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
        age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
       // alert(age);
        return age;
    }
```

this is very simple to find the age using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you construct DOB properly, create:

```
now = Date() //right now
```

use the date.getTime() function to get time in milliseconds.  Divide the difference of them by by the milliseconds in a

```
one_year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
years = (now.getTime() - DOB.getTime())/one_year;
```

Put this in a callback for any change in any of your date fields and display the result wherever you like.

Comment: that'll be out of sync by a few days because of several leap years - as most people are more than 4 years old, 365.25 would be more accurate (tho still not perfect)

Comment: yes i noticed that on yours right after i submitted, good point.  I've heard that years divisible by 100 but not 400 are not leapyears, so i guess 365+(1.0/4)-(1.0/100)+(1.0/400) =
365.2425 would be best =P

Comment: of course careful comparisons would be better, but who's got time for that?

Comment: yes, but how many ppl are 100+ years old? its unlikely that many people using this site were born before 1901 (1900 is the last year where the 365.25 avg doesn't hold) and i feel it is also unlikely this code will still be used in 2100 ( the next year this rule won't hold ;))